# Only see results when disconnected

Tags: node.js, socket.io, disconnect

I've been messing around with node.js/socket.io on a VPS, trying to do a basic send & receive. Seems to authorise okay and everything and I get this on the VPS: `websocket writing 5:::{"name":"news","args":[{"hello":"world"}]}` although I only see anything on the client when they've disconnected. After they're disconnected I get the word "world" shown. Am I doing something wrong, as shouldn't I see that word while they're still connected? Thanks for the help.

I'm using this code:

**Client:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>web sockets</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://IP-ADDRESS/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io

.connect('http://IP-ADDRESS:80');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        writeMessage(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });

    function writeMessage(msg) {
        var msgArea = document.getElementById("msgArea");
        if (typeof msg == "object") {
            msgArea.innerHTML = msg.hello;
        }
        else {
            msgArea.innerHTML = msg;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="msgArea">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Server:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later I'm now using pure websockets. I got socket.io working eventually (can't remember what the problem here was) but it didn't work how I wanted. Websockets work great however.